# animation don't work in box

Tags: css, animation

The problem is about the CSS3 `-webkit-keyframes` and the `-webkit-box-align` property.

Pls visit http://codepen.io/pleasureswx123/pen/fljFH to get more details.

```
/* css code */   
<style>
    .box {
        display:-webkit-box;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        border:1px solid lightblue;
        margin:0 auto;`enter code here`
        -webkit-box-align:end;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
    }
    .inner {
        background:red;
        width:50%;
    }
    .box:hover {
        -webkit-animation:boxalign ease-in 1s infinite;
    }
    /*following don't work*/
    @-webkit-keyframes boxalign {
        0%   { -webkit-box-align : end }
        100% { -webkit-box-align : start }
    }
    </style>
   /* html code */   
    <div class="box">
       <div class="inner">safd</div>
    </div>
```

Dose CSS3 `-webkit-keyframes` support the `-webkit-box-align` property? Why there is no change in my demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-align

in the end of this page you see the "Browser compatibility" and chrome doesn't support box-align.